# mac term + tmux, send left ctrl + cmd + up/down arrow keys

Tags: macos, terminal, tmux

I recently started using a mac at work and I migrated over my dotfiles which work great on a linux setup. I have my Tmux shortcuts to resize the current pane. Which works fine for left right arrow, but up/down arrow are not working. Seams like max os is swallowing the commands. How can I get all of the following to work.

```
# tmux.conf
bind -n C-Left resize-pane -L 10
bind -n C-Right resize-pane -R 10
bind -n C-Down resize-pane -D 5
bind -n C-Up resize-pane -U 5
```

Cheers

Comment: Ironically, C-up and C-down work fine for me in iTerm2 under macOS, but C-left and C-right conflict with the system-level keyboard shortcut for switching spaces (i.e., virtual desktops). (I get *different* behavior between iTerm2 and Terminal, which I'm not really inclined to track down at the moment, since I never use Terminal. Suffice to say, your terminal emulator may also affect how the Control keys are interpreted.)

Comment: I read somewhere that installing iTerm2 might fix this but looks like it has it's own issues.